# Why is my answer to this multichoose counting problem wrong?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm having trouble with the following problem:

An ice-cream vendor sells eleven kinds of ice-cream. In how many different
ways can I buy six cones, some or even all of which could be the same?

I know that one way to answer this is with multichoose or "stars and bars" as I was taught. That method of solution makes total sense to me.

However, before I learned about multichoose, I approached the problem with the following answer:

$11 \cdot 11 \cdot 11 \cdot 11 \cdot 11 \cdot 11 = 11^{6}$.

My reasoning was each time we go to choose a cone, we have 11 ice cream flavors to choose from so its $11^{6}$.

I can't figure out why this is not the case, even though I know it isn't -- can anyone help me understand?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because order of selection doesn't matter.
Let's $1,2,..11$ denote the ice cream types. Then by your calculation, you are counting a 6-tuple $(x,y,z,w,v,u)$, where $x,y,z,w,v,u$ are denoting the type of ice cream you have selected on $1,2,3,4,5,6$ attempt respectively.

But here (1,1,2,3,1,2) is same as (1,2,1,3,2,1). Since in both cases you choose same number of ice-creams of each type even though the order of selection is different. The crucial part is that, here the objects(ice creams) of each type are indistinguishable from each other. In other words, you can't differentiate two type 1 ice cream from each other. That's why two selection are same if and only if you have ended up selecting same number of ice-creams of each type. That's why you need to employ multi-choosing. You can find more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).

Comment: Oh, duh! I see now. I can't believe I totally forgot about this. 

How would one fix this issue of overcounting? is the fix just multichoosing?

Comment: yes, exactly. I expanded my answer a little bit. Hope it will be useful.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand this now. I feel a little silly for not catching this before!